# How to find the nearest point Postgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis, spatial-query

I have two tables in Postgis. Table of plats and table of kindergartens...
I would like to find the closest kindergraten from the given plat (ogc_fid=1397632) from another table. Both of them are points. I have tried something like that, but it still loading the result, probably something is wrong...

```
SELECT
  name
FROM
  kindergarten, plats
ORDER BY
  ST_Transform(kindergarten.geom,5514) <->
  (SELECT geom FROM plats where ogc_fid=1397632)
LIMIT 1;
```

Im not sure if can be a problem that table plats has SRID (Geometry(point,5514)) and table kindergartens has SRID (Geometry(point,3857) Those has been imported from OSM). Does it have some role that SRID is changed in SQL query and not before running them itself?
Do some of you know where is the problem? Im a beginner in spatial queries...

Thank you very much.

Comment: hey @Marty can you also add the create table statement and a few inserts? also, if there is an error message, please add it.

Comment: Why the cross join with `plats`  if you are then doing a scalar subselect in the `order by`? If I understand you correctly, you should just remove the `plats` table from the `FROM` list

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name removing of plats table from from list helped:) Thank you very much. BTW do you know how to write to show the distance betwen the given plat and the nearest point?? It will really help me a lot...